# Wordpress - common fields for posts

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I added a new custom post in Wordpress and named it `Products`.
In admin menu in `Products` I have two links - `All Products` and `New Product`.

Everything works perfectly, each product has it's own permalink, fields and so on.

**Question:** 
What shall I do to have a few editable fields to be common for all products?
I mean, I wish to edit a field just a single time in admin and it shall display on all product pages.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API).
There is no built-in way to do it at a custom post type level.

You could also define a secondary custom post type ("All Products Details") and attach it to every `Product` you create as a custom field on it, but then you also have to implement an automated way of setting defaults for custom fields ([Here's a way to do this.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29355/is-there-a-way-to-set-default-custom-fields-when-creating-a-post)).